Ngx color RGBA and HSLA inputs are not working properly
ngx color RGBA and HSLA inputs are not working, Scenario is First I will change input value 255 to 0 and user don't like that color he can undo value 0 to 255 and he switching to another input or focus-outing input. but input value is not showing 255, it is showing 25. If you not understand properly. Please watch this video. You can check this issue in my example project.
Note: I posted this question under the issues section of that library, the GitHub issue link here, but it seems that this is an old repository that is not being maintained, because I have not received any answer." I hope you can kindly give me some direction of what is wrong.
